# Generating a random number per customer

Tags: php

I have this section of a form I need for my customer signup sheet I am creating.

My goal is check if the customer exists, and if they do, output the customerid into an input box. If the customer does not exist, a 6 digit number should be generated in the input box instead.

Here my code:

```
if(!empty($row['customerid'])) {
    echo '<input class="input-xlarge focused" disabled id="focusedInput" name="customerID" value="'.$row['customerid'].'">';
} else {
    $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid='$six_digit_random_number'";
    $loop = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($loop == 10) {
            echo "CANNOT GENERATE RANDOM NUMBER";
            die();
        }
        $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        $loop++;
    }
    echo '<input class="input-xlarge focused" disabled id="focusedInput" name="customerID" value="'.$six_digit_random_number.'">';
}
```

My question is, will the while loop actually stop duplicates from being made, or is there something I am overlooking?

--UPDATE
I switched out my original `$six_digit_random_number` with a number that already exists in the database, and the while loop did not change the number at all.

So I guess my updated question is, how can I check if the number has been used before?

Comment: why exactly do you even have to? is AUTO_INCREMENT not an option for some reason? (also: your code *will* inevitably fail once you hit a million customers)

Comment: No, it will loop though rows, which has no correlation to the random number.

Comment: Do you want random, or Unique, or both? is the question.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I want the numbers to be random per customer, not sequential.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - why?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix random I don't care too much about, as long as its not sequential. It must be unique. My thoughts were, if the row exists with that number, it should be regenerated.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton a) why? b) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72212/randomizing-the-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: Try this it's not a number, though http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It must be a number, easier to enter later, as requested by my client.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Requested by my client.

Comment: The only why to make them unique is to store them all in a database table, and when you generate them check if you ever created it before.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix they ARE saved in the database table. When a customer number is created, once the form is filled out it is stored. That's my question. I'm not sure how to loop to keep on generating until it is unique.

Comment: is this code being used during user registration? I typically don't share the user id with the end user. Could you use username as the unique factor?

Comment: you should let the DB generate them with [uuid-sort](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short)

Comment: @user3605352 This is a unique id given to a customer so they can be identified easier.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I need it displayed on the same page for the clerk checking out the customer.

Comment: When you use auto increment you can ask mysql the last inserted id which will be the customer id and display it on the same page for the clerk

Comment: @user3605352 It cannot be sequential.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I answered it, don't feel like testing it though ... lol

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach; as it stands customers could both end up with the same number.

Comment: Not, if the number is saved in the DB and when a new user needs to be created you create a number and check for it to exist in the DB.  Performance wise, it's blah, but it will work.

Comment: @l'L'l that's what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I already solved it. Cheers!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: You should use a unique hash or UUID for each customer — that way no two people will get the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have to do something like this ( untested )

```
   $sql = "SELECT customerid FROM customers WHERE customerid=:random_number";
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  do{
       //generate random number
       $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
       //search for it
       $stmt->excute([':random_number' => $six_digit_random_number]);
       if( !$stmt->fetch() ){
           //exit loop if it matches.
           break;
       }
  }while(true);


  //$six_digit_random_number  save user with the unique number
```

Let me break the logic down for you.

When you create a new user, you need an infinite loop.  On each iteration of that loop

- Make a random number
- Check against existing

Now when `fetch` returns false that means the number was never saved, so just use `break` to exit the loop.  The last value of `$six_digit_random_number` is still set.  So, after you exit the loop insert the new user with that number.

Next user cannot have the same number because, `fetch` will return a result, and the loop will continue and generate a new number.  And so on, until such time as it creates one not in use.

The main drawback is if you have a lot of users you could make a bunch of queries against the DB, make sure to set that field to be an `int` and have a Unique index in the schema. That will improve the query performance, as will returning only one field ( that's all you need ) instead of `*`

Make sense.

-note- I like to use the `do{ }while(true);` syntax for this as it's less likely to be mistaken as a typo latter.  It's just more readable then using `while(true){  }` other then that the only difference is with a do loop the loop happens before the evaluation so `do{ }while(0)` will run 1 time where `while(0){}` will not.  In this case that doesn't matter though.

Comment: I'm getting an error, it says `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::excute()` - I switched to sqlite for so long, and have only used procedural x.x

Comment: That's because I use PDO, and you never said what you used.  Both have `$result->fetch()`

Comment: My apologies, I'm using procedural

Comment: I havent used mysqli in about 4 years, but I think its `mysqli_query($sql)`

Comment: As I said ( Untested )

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - see I told you it would work ... 7+ years PHP told me it would.  Cheers.

Comment: Well I had to change it up a bit, but it def put me on the right track. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, I don't feel like making a table and starting apache, and all that Jazz

Comment: While this works I can only recommend against it. An infinite loop hitting the db with *random* numbers is just asking for slow performance. There is no guarantee you'll get a free number in reasonable time. At the very least, keep track of the tried numbers. Likewise, preparing the query *inside* the loop is wasting resources. If your db driver is set to use server side prepares, it will hit the db twice for each number. Prepare the query *once* outside the loop. Also, why do you interpolate the number into the query when you are using prepared statements?

Comment: @Gordon - while I appreciate the feedback, and even agree with the prepared statements ( Updated ), the OP is not using PDO, which I know same thing can be done in mysqli, but it's kind of a moot point.  Performance wise I mentioned that a bit, although not as eloquently.  But, if you know of a better way to achieve the results the OP wants, your more then free to post and answer.

Comment: Which specifically what that is, is a non-sequential, random, 6 digit number that is unique to the customer table.   I did suggest using `uniqid()` instead. Which would be far simpler method, but that's not what the OP wanted. Its not an approach I like either, but I don't see a decent alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I agree your answer does what the OP asks for. It's not wrong but bad practise. There is no reason to hit the database with potentially thousands of requests just to get a number. There was several recommendations on how to achieve this in the comments to the question. In addition, instead of trying to find a free number by going over existing users, you could just create a lookup table (id, user) with all the IDs from 100000 to 999999 prepopulated in id and then selecting a random id where user = null. then update/delete the user column on registration/deletion.

Comment: @Gordon - actually I really like the lookup idea, then it's one query, and you can use something like `Order By RAND() Limit 1`.  so it's non-sequential.  That would be close to 10^6 number or rows though, that is if they were all filled in and a bit more complicated to explain.

Comment: Exactly. Just one random lookup versus potentially thousands. Given the range in `mt_rand(100000, 999999)` it would be 899999 rows. Any decent database should have no problem handling that amount of rows in little time.

Comment: I suppose if it's a indexed int field, we have a a table at work with 90 million rows but that is 35GB ( no Blobs either ), moving it to mongoDB as it gits hit about 1.5 billion times a month  ( we have a search service that uses RabbitMQ and runs over 100k searches a minute). Anyway, thanks for the Ideas and Chat.  Good Night.